# Xamarin Forms - Change View's location in a Grid

Tags: xamarin, gridview, xamarin.forms

I have a grid on my page with a few items.

I want to change the location/span of these items in C#.

On Xaml I can do this:

```
<Grid>
    <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="2"/>
</Grid>
```

I could do `grd.Children.Remove` and then `grd.Children.Add` in the new position, but is there another way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public MyPage()
{
    var grid = new Grid();
    var lbl1 = new Label { Text= "lbl1" };
    var lbl2 = new Label { Text = "lbl2" };
    grid.Children.Add(lbl1);
    grid.Children.Add(lbl2);
    Grid.SetRow(lbl1, 1);
    Grid.SetRow(lbl2, 0);
    this.Content = grid;
}
```

However I would recommend not to do it dynamically but once in the constructor. 
More info in the [official doc](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.Grid/).

Comment: I can just use this without specifying the grid?

Comment: `g.Children.Add(lbl, 0, 0);`
`Grid.SetRow(lbl, 1);` would work?

Comment: Nice, it doesn't even need the `Grid` object. Thanks!

Comment: In addition to my example please check the documentation link I provided. It also contains examples. Glad to help.